# Sort Array php codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Through a series of SQL queries I have obtained an array. I can not do the sort in SQL but I have to sort the multidimensional array -

```
 Array
(
    [133] => Array
        (
            [pr] => 77.5062
            [service_pr] => 1
            [al] => 100
            [service_al] => 1
            [name] => item 1  
        )

    [134] => Array
        (
            [pr] => 79.60
            [service_pr] => 1
            [al] => 100
            [service_al] => 1
            [name] => item 2
        )
    [135] => Array
        (
            [pr] => 88.40
            [service_pr] => 1
            [al] => 100
            [service_al] => 1
            [name] => item 3
        )
)
```

How can I sort the array in ascending order on the key "pr"?

Comment: Can you share what you've tried?

Comment: You can try the function in PHP called uasort: http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php

Answer (score 3):

Use [`usort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) function:

```
usort($array, function($a, $b) { return $a['pr'] - $b['pr']; });
```

If you want descending order just replace `$a` with `$b` and `$b` with `$a`:

```
usort($array, function($a, $b) { return $b['pr'] - $a['pr']; });
```

### [Live preview](https://eval.in/191459)